# Updating PHP.ini on a GoDaddy Hosted site

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to PHP programming so I apologize if I am missing the obvious.

I have a site hosted at GoDaddy (Windows, PHP5, MySQL 5).  I read this article: [GoDaddy FAQ](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1085) and created a php5.ini file in the root folder but when I try to connect to the database, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function mysql_connect() in
>   D:\Hosting\4132900\html\beta\data\dbConnection.php
>   on line 13

All I have in my ini file is:

```
[Date]
date.timezone = "US/Eastern"
```

When I upload my entire php.ini file (and rename it to php5.ini), I get Page Not Found errors (404).

Answer (score 3):

I dont think Windows hosting allows for custom PHP5.ini :(

I check their help site and that article you linked to was for Linux servers.

Also, comparing plans on this page: http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/shared.asp?ci=9009
shows that Linux allows custom PHP5.ini but not Windows

I wonder if trying to use one screws up the PHP and makes the "mysql_connect" function you are trying to use not be available.

Answer (score 1):

I just beat my head against the keyboard to find the solution for editing the php.ini in godaddy. phpinfo() returns a path I cannot access (argh!). Solution: upload your own into the root of your **public_html** folder.

Apparently dependent on the version of godaddy you have, the file name is different.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8913/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-phpini-need-to-use

I was so fed up, I created identical files called **php.ini**, **php5.ini**, and **.user.ini** and copied them into the root of my www, public_html, and the domain root directory. After that everything started working.

From my reading, there may be a situation where you would have to go to "system processes" and restart the php process (I couldn't find that and didn't have any active php processes).

There's some good info here as well. Scroll down to the godaddy portion.

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/

Answer (score 0):

according to this page they specifically say to use php5.ini with Windows Accounts:
[GoDaddy article](http://help.godaddy.com/article/5647?isc=&locale=en#windows)

"NOTE: You must use php5.ini files with Windows hosting accounts, not php.ini."