# What caused this "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on an app for a couple weeks now, using GoDaddy, Windows Server (I know it sucks) everything seemed ok, I have been a PHP programmer for about a year now and have never come across something like this, I have been connecting to a mysql db all day and all of a sudden I'm getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect() on Line 6
```

Could some type of a syntax error be causing this?

I was coding a curl that pulled an XML Feed because I couldn't use file_get_contents due to allow_url_fopen = off which seems to be impossible to change on godaddy with a windows server, and all of a sudden I got this error.

What could be causing this?

Here's the Code in question:

session_start();

$hostname = "test.com";
 $user = "root";
 $pw = "passwd";

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname,$user,$pw)
 or die("couldnt connect to db");
 $db = mysql_select_db ('mydb',$connection)
 or die("couldnt find db");

I created a PHP5.ini to try to fix the allow_url_fopen and just found this question which could be related: [Updating PHP.ini on a GoDaddy Hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732289/updating-php-ini-on-a-godaddy-hosted-site)

I have deleted the PHP5.ini file from the server, but the error still hasn't gone away, maybe it needs some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the problem god window sucks

[Updating PHP.ini on a GoDaddy Hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732289/updating-php-ini-on-a-godaddy-hosted-site)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the MySQL extension is not installed for your PHP installtion.  Create a php file and enter this:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

See if you find a section called MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they put a PHP installation up without MySQL installed. Sometimes hosts make that mistake.

Try and find an entry for MySQL in `phpinfo();`.

Also, see what `function_exists('mysql_connect')` says.

Comment: Strangely enough function_exists('mysql_connect') prints 1

Comment: 'mistake' is putting it a bit bluntly, `mysqli` (it's not called 'improved' for nothing) and `PDO` have been around quite a while.

Comment: This is where RedHat/CentOS rules. `yum install php-mysql`. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Administrative tools / services / MySQL  : Start ! 
Thats it.